# ASP MVC controller method not being called properly via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is an Ajax call I make to a controller whenever a user clicks on a certain icon on my ASP MVC3 View. It is supposed to call a method in the controller by the name of`PopDetails`, however after setting a breakpoint in the controller I can see this is not happening. I tried using both URLs listed below, however neither has worked. Since this is the first time I've used Ajax, I'm not really sure what's going on. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Ajax code from View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetProgramDetails(pgmname) {

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '~/BatchProgramsContoller/PopDetails',
            //url: '~/BatchProgramsContoller/PopDetails',
            data: { programName: pgmname },
            dataType: 'html'
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            $('#programExplanation').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Method from `BatchProgramsController`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string PopDetails(string programName)
    {
        BatchPrograms batchprograms = db.BatchPrograms.Find(programName);
        if (batchprograms == null) return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append(batchprograms.ProgramName + " - " + batchprograms.ShortDescription);
        s.Append("<br />Job Names: " + batchprograms.PrdJobName + ", " + batchprograms.QuaJobName );
        s.Append("<br /> " + batchprograms.Description);
        return s.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: try dropping the ~ and just use /BatchProgramsContoller/PopDetails

Comment: can you put a break point on the ajax call? does it get called?

Comment: Yes. I used Chrome's Developer Console, set a couple breakpoints and saw that the Ajax was getting called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
url: '~/BatchProgramsContoller/PopDetails',
```

should be changed to

```
url: '~/BatchPrograms/PopDetails',
```

or more likely

```
url: '/BatchPrograms/PopDetails',
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally considered bad practice in .net mvc to hard code urls as done in the answer above.

I would use

```
url: '@Url.Action("BatchPrograms", "PopDetails")',
```

This way if your routes change for any reason the mvc url helper takes care of it.

Comment: that's true Rik. But I think Neal already knows that. While it's bad practice to use hard url's, it's sadly common for developers to use hard urls while developing annoying **syntax-unforgiving-javascript** code.